# Frequency in Human sexuality bisexual polyandry and polygamy and others?

Tags: social-psychology, sexuality

I've been studying human sexuality and I have a question which I do not know the answer nor do I exactly know how to research. In the psychology of human sexuality specifically bisexuals what percentage are completely monogamous, polyandry, polygamy or (I don't know the word for having multiple partners of either sexes). Like mutual participation relationships like multiple bisexuals, combinations of bisexuals, heterosexuals and homosexuals. Generally and then specifically in the USA are these relationships typically stable and do they last lifetimes?

Comment: So to paraphrase, are you asking: To what extent are bisexuals in monogamous long term relationships? And to what extent do bisexuals engage in longer term relationships with more than one partner or either sex?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim yes and how is it normally distributed like mmw wwm wwmm ect